# How to create event with filled property dataTransfer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, simulate

I have local html file with javascript code.

I should cover drag & drop by tests.

It uses only IE.

In javascript code event "drop" is caught and content of dataTransfer (e.dataTransfer.getData("Text")) is analysed.

In test I simulate event with next code:

```
event = document.createEventObject();
```

Here event which contains dataTransfer == null is created.

Write is impossible, because property is read only.

```
target.fireEvent("ondrop", event);
```

Event is fired in javascript code, but dataTransfer is null.

I should put some test element in dataTransfer.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You should setup an jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the CustomEvent interface, I'm not sure if it works in IE though.

```
var event = new CustomEvent('build', { 'detail': elem.dataset.time });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent#Adding_custom_data_.E2.80.93_CustomEvent